# d3 v4 + react + es6 + crossfilter: Selection.exit().remove() not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, crossfilter

I'm using [crossfilter.js](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and [d3.js v4](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v4.0.0/CHANGES.md) with ES6 style React in an attempt to make dimensional charts with context brushing. Essentially, I took [this example](https://codepen.io/markehost/pen/Maryxx) and converted it to ES6.

The problem I have is `selection.exit().remove()` is not working such that on each redraw, more and more circles are appended to the svg g element. Redraws are triggered when a brush is created. I checked by running

```
selection.exit()
  .attr('class', d => {
    console.log('anything');
    return 'anything';
  })
  .remove();
```

but nothing was outputted so I'm thinking my data selection is not valid.

Here is the context:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); // the mounted svg element

  const svg = d3.select(el)
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 500);

  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(32,32)');

  let circles = g.append('g')
    .selectAll('circle');

  const brushGroup = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'brush')
    .call(brush);

  function redraw() {
    const all = group.all(); // crossfilter group returns an array

    xAxisGroup.call(xAxis);
    yAxisGroup.call(yAxis);

    circles = circles.data(all, d => d); // keyFn for data constancy

    circles.enter().append('circle')
      .attr('r', radius)
      .attr('cx', plotX) // radius + plotX/Y are simple curry functions
      .attr('cy', plotY);

    circles.exit().remove(); // not working!!
  }

  redraw();
}
```

I am also aware of this change in [d3-selection](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v4.0.0/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection) in v4 but I'm not super confident which lines are my `update` and which ones are my `update + enter`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: An `exit` selection is, after you bind the data to a selection, all those elements that were left with no data referring to them. Now look carefully at your `let circles`: they are not bound to any data. You have to define correctly your enter, update and exit selections. Right now they are not correctly defined.

Comment: What about when I set `circles = circles.data(all, d => d)`.. does that not create a proper join selection hence `circles.enter()` and `circles.exit()`?

Comment: do you have unique ids for your circles data something like this `circles = circles.data(all, d => d.id)`

Comment: @John, Yes, it does: *I* was the one not looking carefully, I read `circles.data` where it is in fact `circles = circles.data`. Moving on: try to remove that `append("g")` from circles, I mean, put it anywhere else, not in `let circles` assignment.

Comment: @Gerardo I tried removing the nested `g` but it did not help. I do need the parent `g` because there are sibling `g`s.. The DOM structure looks like `svg --> g --> g, g, g, g`

Comment: @Cyril, I don't have a unique id and from what I see when I log the key function, the data is not changing at all when I draw brushes. Shouldn't there be no new DOM elements then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is one of 2 things. Probably #1 below. It's a bit hard to tell with out a working example to test things out in, but here you go:

1. I believe that the `selectAll` and the `data` join should happen together in the `redraw` function. Because you never redo the `selectAll` in the redraw function, your selection will never contain any elements. If you check your `enter` and `exit` selections in your `redraw` function, your `enter` selection will always contain all your data points because the underlying selection is empty.
2. That your data key function returns an object. Since the object is the result of Crossfilter's `group.all`, they should be comparable by reference, but it would be safer to do `circles.data(all, d => d.key)`.

The solution should be to do something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); // the mounted svg element

  const svg = d3.select(el)
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 500);

  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(32,32)');

  let circlesGroup = g.append('g'); // Just hang on to the group

  const brushGroup = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'brush')
    .call(brush);

  function redraw() {
    const all = group.all(); // crossfilter group returns an array

    xAxisGroup.call(xAxis);
    yAxisGroup.call(yAxis);

    let circles = circlesGroup // Do the selection and data join here
      .selectAll('circle')
        .data(all, d => d.key); // Have the key function return a key, not an object

    circles.enter().append('circle')
      .attr('r', radius)
      .attr('cx', plotX) // radius + plotX/Y are simple curry functions
      .attr('cy', plotY);

    circles.exit().remove();
  }

  redraw();
}
```

Comment: I feel like I tried every pattern except that one! It was mainly because after the manual invocation of `redraw()`, I export circles along with the chart (see the codepen) but it turns out the only thing I use the exported chart for is to `redraw()` so this makes perfect sense! Now if I can just get my d3 v4 histogram to work. Many thanks!